# Writing a Java JAR for spark

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

Sorry if this seems like a silly question. I need to write a very simple String processing function for someone else's Spark application, but I have limited/no experience with Spark. I was told that I could just write it in Java and deliver the jar file.

I'm a bit confused on how the design would look like though? Would it work if I just create a standard class that contains the method (without any Spark-specific code)? How would this be initialized/called from the (Scala) Spark application after the jar is imported?

Comment: You can write a custom Java function and register it as a Spark UDF. Or you can write a function that does some processing on a Spark DataFrame or DataSet. If you can use the existing Spark DataFrame functions without a UDF, that is probably the preferred way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to add any Spark specifics (unless you need to use Spark classes). Here is an example:

```
evan@vbox:~> cat MyClass.java
public class MyClass
{
    public static int add(int x, int y)
    {
        return x + y;
    }
}
evan@vbox:~> javac MyClass.java
evan@vbox:~> jar cvf MyJar.jar MyClass.class
added manifest
adding: MyClass.class(in = 244) (out= 192)(deflated 21%)
evan@vbox:~> spark --jars ./MyJar.jar
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.0.1
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.11.8 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_111)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> MyClass.add(2,3)
res0: Int = 5
```

In this case Scala was able to use `scala.Int` as the Java primitive `int` so there was no Scala/Java interoperability considerations. Depending on your function you may need to think about this, but that is a Scala-Java issue, not a Spark issue.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Is there any way to use objects in Spark, rather than using static methods to avoid doing some redundant things?

Comment: You can use any Java structure in Scala so just write out your Java code as you please and your Spark Dev will be able to use it. Just watch out for things like collections, you will need to allow conversions

Comment: Here is a [writeup of general difference](http://www.codecommit.com/blog/java/interop-between-java-and-scala), [here is one on collections](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/conversions-between-java-and-scala-collections.html).

Comment: @L.Pardus FYI: [please upvote and accept answers rather than using thank you comments](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)